# Yarn --link-duplicates creates error while building

Tags: babeljs, yarnpkg, babel-core

I run yarn install --link-duplicates in order to install packages. I get the following error

```
NOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/.../front/node_modules/@svgr/webpack/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules
```

The node_modules doesn't exist in the specific path. If i run it without --link-duplicates it runs without any error.

This happens after upgrading from "@babel/core": "^7.2.2.", to "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",

Is there any way to link-duplicates except a specific module? I try to avoid removing the --link-duplicates, because it doudbles the size of the node_modules